# Decrypt file in Node.js encrypted using OpenSSL

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm using the following command to encrypt a video file in openssl

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -nosalt -a -in movie.mp4 -out movie.enc -k skdjfsldkfjsldkjfsldkf
```

And using the following code to decrypt the file but I keep getting bad decrypt error what am I doing wrong?

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var fs = require('fs');
cipher_name   = 'aes-256-cbc';
password      = 'skdjfsldkfjsldkjfsldkf';
decoder       = crypto.createDecipher( cipher_name, password );
text_crypt    = fs.readFileSync( 'movie.enc' );
chunks        = [];
chunks.push(decoder.update( text_crypt, 'binary' ));
chunks.push(decoder.final( 'binary' ));
fs.writeFileSync( 'nodemovie.mp4',chunks.join('','binary') );
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Decipher.final (crypto.js:160:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\java\index.js:12:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
```

I should be able to encrypt video in openssl and decrypt in node and java at the same time

Comment: why you tagged as java?

Comment: because i want to decrypt the same file in java ... I've mentioned the same in my qn too

Comment: @SushilSudhakaran - Pick your poison - decrypt in Node.js, or decrypt in Java. Since the title indicates Node.js, how about if the answers focus on Node.js. When you are ready, ask another question specific to Java.

Comment: `-k skdjfsldkfjsldkjfsldkf` is different than `-K skdjfsldkfjsldkjfsldkf`. Also see [EVP_BytesToKey](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_BytesToKey(3)) man page, and [EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt when using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37997354/608639).

Comment: Here are some similar questions and answers: [Decrypting AES256 with node.js returns wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21292142/608639), [Nodejs decrypt using crypto error wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23111388/608639), [Getting error wrong final block length while decrypting AES256](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32038267/608639), [How to decipher string in node js which is encrypted in crypto.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28359128/608639), [What's wrong with nodejs crypto decipher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12219499/608639)

Comment: This depends on your OpenSSL version. Newer OpenSSL versions use EVP_BytesToKey with SHA-256 instead of MD5 like node.js does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting AES256 with node.js returns wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292142/decrypting-aes256-with-node-js-returns-wrong-final-block-length)

Answer (score 0):

as jww said, openssl `-k` and `-K` are not the same.

```sh
openssl aes-256-cbc -nosalt -in movie.mp4 -out movie.enc -k skdjfsldkfjsldkjfsldkf -p
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
key=ED67064595132E4F1154C557A3C103999CF719B66855B6563C6B35D346CDE40E
iv =4FB8711CAD9659FF2F1DCE33A7D3E0B7
```

knowing `key` and `iv`

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');

var fs = require('fs');
cipher_name   = 'aes-256-cbc';
//password      = 'skdjfsldkfjsldkjfsldkf';
//decoder       = crypto.createDecipher( cipher_name, password );
iv            = Buffer.from('4FB8711CAD9659FF2F1DCE33A7D3E0B7','hex');
key           = Buffer.from('ED67064595132E4F1154C557A3C103999CF719B66855B6563C6B35D346CDE40E','hex');

decoder       = crypto.createDecipheriv( cipher_name, key, iv );
text_crypt    = fs.readFileSync( 'movie.enc' );
chunks        = [];
chunks.push(decoder.update( text_crypt, 'binary' ));
chunks.push(decoder.final( 'binary' ));
fs.writeFileSync( 'nodemovie.mp4',chunks.join('','binary') );
```